# How to spawn objects to pre scanned area on hololens 2

Tags: hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

First of all my usage scenario is as follows;

I want to scan my room with spatial mapping method and then add some 3D models on unity to this scan. When I start using the hololens, if I am in this room, I want the objects I add to spawn at the point where I add them.
How can I do this without using an azure spatial anchor?

Comment: I think Azure Spatial Anchor can achieve your needs. If possible, please explain why you don't use it. What are you concerned about?
In addition to Azure Spatial Anchor, you can also try QR code, please refer to [QR code tracking - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/qr-code-tracking-unity).

Comment: @ZuochengWang-MSFT It may not be possible for me to maintain the internet connection all the time. Any chance to use Azure spatial anchor locally?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spatial Anchor locally, which stores anchors on the device. Please refer to [World locking and spatial anchors in Unity - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/spatial-anchors-in-unity?tabs=wlt) for more information.